# Redirecionar a partir de uma URL dentro do laravel

Tags: php, laravel, apache

Boa tarde, estou com um problema:

Tenho um sistema para a empresa que trabalho que é usado apenas internamente, então ele é acessado apenas através de VPN, porem vamos abrir esse sistema para clientes externos, então tenho a url:

```
https://sistemainterno.com.br
```

e o clientes:

```
https://sistemaclientes.com.br
```

O problema:

ambos os sistemas usam o mesmo backend e frontend, eu queria apenas redirecionar tudo que vem da url "https://sisteclientes.ocm.br" para "https://sistemainterno.com.br/clientes/", o sistema cliente seria apenas um aliás para proteger o caminho interno e liberar apenas as URLs com /clientes/, porem estou com duvida em como fazer isso no laravel... alguem tem alguma solução?

Obrigado desde já

Answer (score 1):

Você tem as seguintes opções

OPÇÃO 1: criar uma rota Route::get('/clientes','SeuController@suaFuncao');

no seu controller criar a função que faz a chamada da view,

```
    public function getView() {

    ## SUAS FUNÇÕES E OBJETOS...

   $cliente = Clientes::all(); #por exemplo
   return view('seudiretorio.suaview')->with('clientes',$clientes);
```

}

OPÇÃO 2: configurar o APACHE para entender que ao invés de /public ele vá para /public/clientes
Exemplo: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-configurar-apache-virtual-hosts-no-ubuntu-16-04-pt

OPÇÃO 3: Quando a pessoa realiza a autenticação você apontar para essa /clientes ao invés do /

No seu Controller >> Auth >> LoginController por exemplo :

```
$token = Users::where('email',$request->email)->select('token')->first();
```

##onde E-mail seria seu campo de login, se for código vc colocaria o input desse código.

```
Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->password, 'token' => $token)
```

**e no protected $redirectTo = '/clientes';**